# input controls disabled in tfoot under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, handlebars.js

JSON returns more than 3 types of student details and for each student succeeded creating a table but among the three for one student of type partner should have some input controls like a checkboxes and buttons available. the problem am facing is that the checkboxes are showing up but the controls are disabled

this is what i have tried

{{i.memberType | fcap}} Member - {{i.name.first}} {{i.name.last}}

```
               <tfoot ng-show="i.memberType == 'PARTNER'">
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="iautho" ng-model="iautho" ng-checked="ctrl.isAuthorized">
                        <label for="iautho">I authorize this member to view and update student information.</label>

                <input type="checkbox" id="ihave" ng-model="ihave" ng-checked="ctrl.isAuthorized">
                <label for="ihave" ng-show="iautho">I have read, understand and voluntarily agree to all the terms and conditions of the
                <a href="#" ng-click="navigate('global.account.agreements',{agreementId:9}, true)">Partner Access Authorization agreement.</a></label>

                <button id="studentdetails" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!ihave">Update
                </button>
                </td></tr>
                <hr class="m-y-1">
               </tfoot>
```

May I know what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

> the problem am facing is that the checkboxes are showing up but the controls are disabled

Your have both `ng-model` and `ng-checked`. You *should not* use `ng-checked` as `ng-model` is enough.

Quick example : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/736/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = true;
}


<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo"/>
</div>
```